# Intersection of a Borel set and its translation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

My idea is to use regularity somehow and use compact sets where this statement clearly holds. This doesn't seem to be working. Is this the right approach? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your idea does work. What problem are you running into when you try it?

Answer (score 3):

Choose $\epsilon>0$. Since $mB<\infty$, there is some $L$ such that
$m (B \setminus [-L,L]^n) < \epsilon$.
Choose $\|x\|_\infty > 2L$. Then $m(B \cap (B + x)) < 2 \epsilon$.

A little elaboration:

> Let $B_0 = B \cap [-L,L]^n, B_1 = B \setminus [-L,L]^n$. Note that if $\|x\|_\infty > 2L$ then $B_0 \cap (B_0 +x) = \emptyset$. Find an upper bound for the measure of $(B_0 \cup B_1) \cap ((B_0+x) \cup (B_1+x))$ by expanding into four sets.

Comment: $\|x\|_\infty = \max_k |x_k|$. You need to do some work, it is not difficult to split $B$ into two parts as above and estimate the measure of in the intersection.

Comment: $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$?????

Comment: It is a norm. It satisfies $\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_2  \le  \sqrt{n} \|x\|_\infty$. Presumably by $\|x\|$ you mean the Euclidean norm $\| \cdot \|_2$?

Comment: The norm is not measure theory. You can use any norm you want, but if you choose $x$ as above then you can see that $[-L,L]^n $ and  $[-L,L]^n +x$ do not intersect, which is the point.

Comment: Figure out how large $x$ has to be to guarantee that $[-L,L]^n $ and  $[-L,L]^n +x$ do not intersect. Good night.

Comment: Why the downvote?